# CURL and JAVA error

Tags: java, curl

I want to program a  CURL [Webservice](https://api.esios.ree.es/archive/getting_a_list_of_archives) Client with Java but it doesn't work.

I want make a client of this

```
curl "https://api.esios.ree.es/archives" -X GET \
-H "Accept: application/json; application/vnd.esios-api-v1+json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Host: api.esios.ree.es" \
-H "Authorization: Token token=\"96c56fcd69dd5c29f569ab3ea9298b37151a1ee488a1830d353babad3ec90fd7\"" \
-H "Cookie: "
```

I make a little program using com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client and ClientResponse but fail. 
The example is that:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource =client.resource("https://api.esios.ree.es/archive");
MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("Accept", "application/json; application/vnd.esios-api-v1+json");
queryParams.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
queryParams.add("Host", "api.esios.ree.es");
queryParams.add("Authorization", "Token token=\"96c56fcd69dd5c29f569ab3ea9298b37151a1ee488a1830d353babad3ec90fd7\"");
queryParams.add("Cookie", " ");
ClientResponse response = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
    + response.getStatus());
}
```

The code response Failed : HTTP error code : 401. Thanks a lot for try to help me.

Comment: looks like you are sending those as queryParams, not headers. see webResource.header(name,value)

Comment: Also I spotted that you use `https://api.esios.ree.es/archives` in first code sample and `https://api.esios.ree.es/archive` in the second

Comment: if that token is sensitive, you might not want to have posted it in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send those values as headers, not query parameters.

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Accept", "application/json; application/vnd.esios-api-v1+json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Host", "api.esios.ree.es")
                .header("Authorization", "Token token=\"TOKEN\"")
                .header("Cookie", " ")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

I'v removed the accept() method as we are setting this with the header() method.

And as pointed out by Ruslan, check you are calling the correct endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Attention! The `client.resource route ("https://api.esios.ree.es/archive");` is incorrect has to be `client.resource ("https://api.esios.ree.es/archives");` if not return `404 error`